# show/hide a tab element using content tabs in elementor

Tags: javascript, tabs, getelementbyid, elementor, queryselector

Im working in elementor free and using the "content tabs" widget from the unlimited elements plugin. I have a couple of tabs, one of which i only want to show when the url has a certain word in it meaning(ie I have results to show), otherwise it should stay hidden. i've tested that part and it works fine as i can hide a section(for example). so i think my issue is that im not getting the result i expect from the "document.getElementById("#motHist")"

This code is sitting inside an html widget.

Id really appreciate some help please to figure out how i can solve this.
Thank you so much!

-Tried getting the element by id using the parent and that works but obviously hides the whole set of tabs(not sure how to then find the child i want)
-Tried queryselector
-Tried googling solutions but not experienced enough to understand how to apply it to elements built by drag and drop and not sure how to build it myself so the tabs use elementId content type(ie the tabs show and hide containers not the default tab content)
-Tried moving the location of the html widget is last ditch mad try

```
<div class="uc_bold_tabs padding r-tabs" id="uc_content_tabs_elementor16836" data-debug="false" data-editor="no">
        <ul class="tabs uc_tab_nav r-tabs-nav">
            
<li class="elementor-repeater-item-03fd7ef r-tabs-tab r-tabs-state-active">
    
    <a href="#uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item1" id="#automotiveRepairs" class="ue-tab-btn r-tabs-anchor">
                       
      <div>Automotive Repairs</div>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="elementor-repeater-item-2bb52a5 r-tabs-state-default r-tabs-tab">
    
    <a href="#uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item2" id="#servicing" class="ue-tab-btn r-tabs-anchor">
                       
      <div>Servicing</div>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="elementor-repeater-item-a0f7092 r-tabs-state-default r-tabs-tab">
    
    <a href="#uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item3" id="#timingBelts" class="ue-tab-btn r-tabs-anchor">
                       
      <div>Timing Belts</div>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="elementor-repeater-item-3a5ea62 r-tabs-state-default r-tabs-tab">
    
    <a href="#uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item4" id="#motPrep" class="ue-tab-btn r-tabs-anchor">
                       
      <div>MOT Prep</div>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="elementor-repeater-item-d722cc8 r-tabs-state-default r-tabs-tab">
    
    <a href="#uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item5" id="#motHist" class="ue-tab-btn r-tabs-anchor" style="display: none;">
                       
      <div>MOT History</div>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="elementor-repeater-item-3b46eba r-tabs-state-default r-tabs-tab">
    
    <a href="#uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item6" id="#brakesClutches" class="ue-tab-btn r-tabs-anchor">
                       
      <div>Brakes &amp; Clutches</div>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="elementor-repeater-item-56a26c0 r-tabs-state-default r-tabs-tab">
    
    <a href="#uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item7" id="#wheelAlignment" class="ue-tab-btn r-tabs-anchor">
                       
      <div>Wheel Alignment</div>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="elementor-repeater-item-998f554 r-tabs-state-default r-tabs-tab">
    
    <a href="#uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item8" id="#customJob" class="ue-tab-btn r-tabs-anchor">
                       
      <div>Custom Jobs </div>
    </a>
</li>

</ul>
        <div class="panel-container">
            <div class="r-tabs-accordion-title"><a href="#uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item1" class="r-tabs-anchor"><div class="uc-tabs-accordion-title">
                       
      <div>Automotive Repairs</div>
    </div>
    <div class="uc-accordion-icon">
      <span class="uc-accordion-icon-expand"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
      <span class="uc-accordion-icon-collapse"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></span>
    </div>
  </a></div><div id="uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item1" class="tab-container panes r-tabs-panel r-tabs-state-active" style="display: none;">
    <div>
                 
                <div class="ue-element active" data-id="eID_automotiveRepairs"></div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="r-tabs-accordion-title"><a href="#uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item2" class="r-tabs-anchor"><div class="uc-tabs-accordion-title">
                       
      <div>Servicing</div>
    </div>
    <div class="uc-accordion-icon">
      <span class="uc-accordion-icon-expand"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
      <span class="uc-accordion-icon-collapse"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></span>
    </div>
  </a></div><div id="uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item2" class="tab-container panes r-tabs-state-default r-tabs-panel" style="display: none;">
    <div>
                 
                <div class="ue-element" data-id="eID_servicing"></div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="r-tabs-accordion-title"><a href="#uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item3" class="r-tabs-anchor"><div class="uc-tabs-accordion-title">
                       
      <div>Timing Belts</div>
    </div>
    <div class="uc-accordion-icon">
      <span class="uc-accordion-icon-expand"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
      <span class="uc-accordion-icon-collapse"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></span>
    </div>
  </a></div><div id="uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item3" class="tab-container panes r-tabs-state-default r-tabs-panel" style="display: none;">
    <div>
                 
                <div class="ue-element" data-id="eID_timingBelts"></div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="r-tabs-accordion-title"><a href="#uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item4" class="r-tabs-anchor"><div class="uc-tabs-accordion-title">
                       
      <div>MOT Prep</div>
    </div>
    <div class="uc-accordion-icon">
      <span class="uc-accordion-icon-expand"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
      <span class="uc-accordion-icon-collapse"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></span>
    </div>
  </a></div><div id="uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item4" class="tab-container panes r-tabs-state-default r-tabs-panel" style="display: none;">
    <div>
                 
                <div class="ue-element" data-id="eID_motPrep"></div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="r-tabs-accordion-title"><a href="#uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item5" class="r-tabs-anchor"><div class="uc-tabs-accordion-title">
                       
      <div>MOT History</div>
    </div>
    <div class="uc-accordion-icon">
      <span class="uc-accordion-icon-expand"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
      <span class="uc-accordion-icon-collapse"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></span>
    </div>
  </a></div><div id="uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item5" class="tab-container panes r-tabs-state-default r-tabs-panel" style="display: none;">
    <div>
                 
                <div class="ue-element" data-id="eID_motHist"></div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="r-tabs-accordion-title"><a href="#uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item6" class="r-tabs-anchor"><div class="uc-tabs-accordion-title">
                       
      <div>Brakes &amp; Clutches</div>
    </div>
    <div class="uc-accordion-icon">
      <span class="uc-accordion-icon-expand"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
      <span class="uc-accordion-icon-collapse"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></span>
    </div>
  </a></div><div id="uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item6" class="tab-container panes r-tabs-state-default r-tabs-panel" style="display: none;">
    <div>
                 
                <div class="ue-element" data-id="eID_brakesClutches"></div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="r-tabs-accordion-title"><a href="#uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item7" class="r-tabs-anchor"><div class="uc-tabs-accordion-title">
                       
      <div>Wheel Alignment</div>
    </div>
    <div class="uc-accordion-icon">
      <span class="uc-accordion-icon-expand"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
      <span class="uc-accordion-icon-collapse"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></span>
    </div>
  </a></div><div id="uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item7" class="tab-container panes r-tabs-state-default r-tabs-panel" style="display: none;">
    <div>
                 
                <div class="ue-element" data-id="eID_wheelAlignment"></div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="r-tabs-accordion-title"><a href="#uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item8" class="r-tabs-anchor"><div class="uc-tabs-accordion-title">
                       
      <div>Custom Jobs </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uc-accordion-icon">
      <span class="uc-accordion-icon-expand"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
      <span class="uc-accordion-icon-collapse"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></span>
    </div>
  </a></div><div id="uc_content_tabs_elementor16836_item8" class="tab-container panes r-tabs-state-default r-tabs-panel" style="display: none;">
    <div>
                 
                <div class="ue-element" data-id="eID_customJobs"></div>
        </div>
</div>

        </div>
  
  <div class="uc-accordion-contents-template" style="display:none">
    <div class="uc-accordion-icon">
      <span class="uc-accordion-icon-expand"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
      <span class="uc-accordion-icon-collapse"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleMOTHist(){
        //get the tab element using tab id
        var smh = document.getElementById("#motHist");

        //if page loads as a result of an MOT hist query, display the tab element otherwise hide 
        url = window.location.href;
        
        if(url.match("/?Reg=") ){
            smh.style.display = "block";     
        }
        else
        {
            smh.style.display = "none";
        }
   
    }

    //toggle mot history tab on page load
    window.onload = function(){
        toggleMOTHist();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to edit your question and add the relevant rendered HTML?

Comment: I’m not sure how to get hold of that..sorry a real newbie. Would I use inspect and copy that?

Comment: Yes, that would be the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you I’ll get that for you as soon as possible

Comment: ok done.. i think. is that ok?

Comment: ok, im sorry but its not working... i have no idea whats happened.. havent changed anything...

Comment: My only idea is I think the Java script is only getting applied when I’m not in editing mode..

Comment: I think I see what the issue is. Your ids seem to have an unnecessary `#` - for example `id="#motHist"` should be `id="motHist"`. Try changing that, and see if it will work. You would need to change that for all of your ids.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The # is there to enable the tab to be accessed as a a link. It seems to work fine when I’m not in editing mode a bit like you can see the html block in editing but not on the running page, same with this I can see the tab always in editing mode but when the site is running it works as I expected. Wasted 2 days trying to fix something that wasn’t broken 